# AngularJS, Bootstrap Modal, Close modal and delete note

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been trying to use a modal as an alert box when deleting a note. When you press "DELETE" I want the modal to pop up as an alert. When you press "OK" on the modal it should close the modal and delete the note.
I am getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - $modal is not defined".
I hope you guys can help an angular-beginner!

Please see this fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/985/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many errors in the jsfiddle.

First be sure to import the angular-ui-boostrap lib (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Then add ui.bootstrap as a dependency of your angular module: `['ui.sortable', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

Finally, you need to inject the $modal service into your controller:

> app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {...}